# deploying angular universal on node.js express server

Tags: node.js, angular, express

angular universal([angular](https://angular.io/guide/universal) or [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering)) can be create three part:

[image]

1. browser folder

   `ng build --prod` to generated static file
2. server folder

   A server bundle by script([bundle](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering#step-3-create-a-new-target-in-angularjson))
3. server.js

   webpack bundle serve ([bundle](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering#step-5-setup-a-webpack-config-to-handle-this-node-serverts-file-and-serve-your-application))

Run `node dist/server.js` can be work on localhost:4000.

But when I have a node.js(express) server, how can I deploy these files?

If I only have one file by `ng build --prod`, I can deploy it on node.js like this.

app.js:

```
 app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist/index.html'));
        });
```

Comment: Did you find a way to deploy it in existing Express server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle has its own express embedded, so just start it like you did on your own machine with `node server.js`.

The recommended way is to use a process manager like pm2. If you want to use pm2, install it with `npm i -g pm2` then start your server as a pm2 process with `pm2 start server.js`

Comment: oh..two individuals that are completely independent.Is this a good way? Is there anything that needs attention?

Comment: I see no major design flaw, your front-end and your backend have different concerns ans generate different logs. If that bothers you, you can still put your backend in the server.ts file, that should totally work if all of the files you use are explicitly imported.

Comment: This way is convenient, I don't have to worry about how the front end should be opened through the back end. I just don't know how everyone is deploying angular+node.js.